# Parsing json string to java with complex datastructure(jackson)

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I am trying to convert the below json string to java object, but i am getting empty object.
Under prop2 object, there can be any number of key value pairs(where key is a string and value is a array )

```
{
"Level1": {
        "prop1": "",
        "prop2": {
            "one": [{
                "ip": "1.2.3.4",
                "port": "100"
            }],
            "ten": [{
                "ip": "10.20.20.10",
                "port": "200"
            }]
        }
}
}
```

I have this class structure, however i am getting ipAndPorts map as empty.

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    static class Root {
        @JsonProperty("Level1")
        private Level1 level1;
    }
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    static class Level1 {
        @JsonProperty("prop2")
        private Prop2 prop2;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    static class Prop2 {
        private Map<String, List<IpAndPort>> ipAndPorts = Collections.emptyMap();
    }
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
     static class IpAndPort {
        @JsonProperty("port")
        private String port;
    }
```

How should my java class look like, to represent "prop2" correctly?

Comment: Class `Prop2` should have two fields, one named `one` and one named `ten`, both of type `IpAndPort` (or rather `Collection<IpAndPort>`, because of the brackets `[ ]`). Class `IpAndPort` can have both fields `ip` and `port`.

Comment: @MarkusPscheidt "one" and "ten" are dynamic. I would not know the values upfront.

Comment: Have you got any influence on the JSON data structure? Because under `prop2` you effectively have a collection, which is however not represented as collection (using `[ ]`) in JSON. A proper collection representation would make it easier to deserialize.

Comment: @MarkusPscheidt Unfortunately no. I can not control json data structure.

Comment: Did you try to use `private Map<String, List<IpAndPort>> ipAndPorts = Collections.emptyMap()` directly instead of `private Prop2 prop2;`? I think you need to omit the `Prop2` class. Otherwise Jackson expects a JSON property called `ipAndPorts` under `prop2`.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich That worked like charm! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record: The problem was solved by using

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
static class Level1 {
    @JsonProperty("prop2")
    private Map<String, List<IpAndPort>> ipAndPorts = Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

directly without the `Prop2` class. Otherwise Jackson would expect a JSON property called `ipAndPorts` under `prop2` JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

I would sudgest that you would first create your Java class the way want it to look like, then use Jackson to serialize it to JSON. you will see what is the structure of resultant JSON and see if and how you will need to modify your class.